# C++11 class in std::map as Value with private constructors

Tags: c++11, private, stdmap

Here is the simplified version of the class which is stored as value in a map which works fine in VS2008 (note that **all** members are private):

```
class Value{
    friend class FriendClass;
    friend class std::map<std::string, Value>;
    friend struct std::pair<const std::string, Value>;
    friend struct std::pair<std::string, Value>;

    Value() {..}
    Value(Value const& other) {..}

    ... rest members...
};
```

Code (called from FriendClass, so this can reach private constructors) :

```
FriendClass::func()
{
    std::map<const std::string, Value> map;
    map.insert(std::make_pair(std::string("x"), Value()));
}
```

This compiles w/o any error in VS2008, but fails on VS2015/C++11:

```
file.cpp(178): error C2664: 'std::_Tree_iterator>>> std::_Tree>::insert(std::_Tree_const_iterator>>>,const std::pair &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::pair' to 'std::pair &&'
      with
      [
          _Kty=std::string,
          _Ty=Value,
          _Pr=std::less,
          _Alloc=std::allocator>
      ]
      and
      [
          _Kty=std::string,
          _Ty=Value
      ]
  file.cpp(178): note: Reason: cannot convert from 'std::pair' to 'std::pair'
      with
      [
          _Kty=std::string,
          _Ty=Value
      ]
  file.cpp(178): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

If I make the Value copy constructor public, it compiles fine in VS2015 as well. 
 
 But that was private with purpose, and only made available for std::map and std::pair. However, it seems in C++11 additional friend access are also necessary to declare. Which are these?

Thank you.

Comment: Your code compiles for me in VS2015, if I call `make_pair` with `std::string("x")` instead of plain `char[]`

Comment: @Zereges: that is strange, as the issue is different. Even if I change to `std::string("x")` I have the same error. Let me change the example to avoid confusion. Are you sure you have all the constructors private in Value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have access to the compilers you mentioned, but here's what I'm seeing on g++ 5.3.

Consider the following essentially-same version of your question:

```
#include <map>                                                                                                                             
#include <utility>


class foo
{
    friend std::pair<const int, foo>;

    foo(const foo &other){}

public:
    foo(){}
};


int main()
{
    using map_t = std::map<int, foo>;

    map_t m;
    m.insert(std::make_pair(2, foo()));
    // m.emplace(2, foo());
}
```

(The default ctor is `public`, but that's non-essential and just makes the example shorter.)

In `main`, note the two lines

```
m.insert(std::make_pair(2, foo()));
// m.emplace(2, foo());
```

Reversing the comments builds fine, but the version shown doesn't:

```
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h: In instantiation of ‘constexpr    std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(_U1&&, const _T2&) [with _U1 = int; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; _T1 = int; _T2 = foo]’:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:281:72:   required from ‘constexpr std::pair<typename std::__decay_and_strip<_Tp>::__type, typename   std::__decay_and_strip<_T2>::__type> std::make_pair(_T1&&, _T2&&) [with _T1 = int; _T2 = foo; typename std::__decay_and_strip<_T2>::__type = foo; typename std::__decay_and_strip<_Tp>::__type = int]’
stuff.cpp:21:34:   required from here
stuff.cpp:9:2: error: ‘foo::foo(const foo&)’ is private
 foo(const foo &other){}
 ^
```

Looking at the source code `std_pair.h` shows that indeed it is trying to call the copy constructor. Unfortunately, you `friend`ed `std::pair`, but not `std::make_pair`.

The `emplace` version doesn't have this problem, but I suspect that this is implementation dependent. In general, if you want a container to store a completely opaque class, I would suggest that you use a container of `std::shared_ptr`s to them. This allows you to completely specify which function/class can create/copy objects in your own code, and makes no assumptions on the library's code.

Comment: `Unfortunately, you friended std::pair, but not std::make_pair.` - I would friend it but it does not help (or I do incorrectly). I tried adding `friend std::pair<std::string, Value> std::make_pair(std::string&&, Value&&);` but same error. I don't see reason to avoid `emplace()` actually, probably that will be the way (even faster), but curious for other solution w/o shared_ptr / emplace / public constructor, as it compiled with "old" c++ w/o issues.

Comment: I tried to explain in my answer, though, why I think it cannot be done cleanly: you can friend a class, or a function, or anything. However, as long as it is not your code, you cannot be sure it doesn't call something else which isn't a friend. So what you have is that in some versions on some compilers `emplace` happens to work, and an older version of yours didn't have an overload of `make_pair` for which it was a problem, etc. IIUC, there is nothing that forbids the next version of `emplace` breaking your code again.

Comment: So `public copy constructor` or `shared_ptr` seems to be the best solution.

Comment: To the best of my understanding - yes. Perhaps someone will surprise me with something I completely didn't think about, though :-)